# Firebase Dynamic Links stop working after IOS app Transfer to new Developer Account

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Our app had dynamic links up and running in the AppStore, but we had to transfer the app to a new developer account. After the transfer dynamic links no longer open the app, going straight to safari. 
The transfer kept the Bundle Identifier the same but the Team ID changed.

I have tried:

-Updating Team ID on Firebase Project Settings

-Re-downloading and importing GoogleService-Info.plst

-Verifying TeamID and AppID correct under https://example.com/apple-app-site-association

-Turning on and off Associate Domains under the app config

I am aware I must click the link in notes or email or iMessage, and I have tried holding down on the link to specify it to open in the app.

I believe my configuration for the app to handle the link is messed up rather than it being on firebase's end, but I cannot figure out what exactly is the issue. Any tips or hints in the right direction are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The problem fixed itself after about a day. Must have something to do with cache